# Abaqus shows axes with different scaling

Tags: abaqus

I am using Abaqus and performing a simulation in a cube with some particles inside. I ran a the simulation using a Python script, for which results look fine. So I saved some images from the Visualization module showing the strain distribution in the cube. A day later, I ran the same Python script but changed one parameter (maximum displacement applied). But now, when I see the results in the Visualization module, the cube looks like a rectangular prism. So I guess there is some sort of scaling applied to the axes. Also, this scaling is applied globally. If I go to Part or Assembly or Mesh, I will see a rectangular prism instead of a cube. I don't know how this happened if my simulation is done using the script and I did not set any changes in how the results are displayed nor I did this when exporting the images.

I have tried to look for options that are related to the scaling of the axis within Abaqus without success. I also tried to open and close Abacus in case it was something particular of the simulation, but I still see the scaling in the axes. Even if I open the odb file from which I got the images that actually show the cube, now show a rectangular prism.

Something that gave me some hope is that in the visualization "Common Plot Option", in the tab Other, in the tab Scaling, there is an uncheck box with the option "Scale coordinates". If I check the box ans set all coordinates to 1, there are no changes. If I know what the scaling factor is, I could just set the sclaing to cancel out that scaling factor. But again I don't know how it was applied.

**UPDATE**: I think the issue solved by itself. I have been working remotely and connecting to a Windows machie with Abaqus via the Microsoft Remote Desktop (from a Mac mini). It seems the issue appears when I use Abaqus from the remote desktop. After closing Abaqus in that Windows machine, then using it in a second Windows machine, then back again in the first Windows machine now I see the cube as a cube. I guess the cause is the remote desktop because some software behaves differently and the visualization software Paraview just won't open.

**UPDATE 2:** I confirmed the issue indeed happens when connecting remotely with Microsoft Remote Desktop from my Mac computer. The issue happens even when using a Python script for generating the figures to avoid opening the user interface. When running the script directly on the computer figures are fine (i.e., the cube looks like a cube). Not sure if when connecting remotely with Microsoft Remote Desktop from a Windows computer the issue will be present.

Comment: I think, the scaling is done for the deformed model. Some times, Abaqus does apply deformation scaling for your model in order to see the deformation clearly. Check, in the same common plot options in "Basic" tab,  if "Deformation Scale Factor" is applied to "Auto-compute" and check the value wirtten in front of it . To avoid this, you could just set "Deformation Scale Factor" as uniform and to the value of 1. or you could write a line in your python script: `session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.commonOptions.setValues(
    uniformScaleFactor=1)`.

Comment: Yes, I found that option in the GUI. However, the issue is that the scaling is applied globally. If I see the cube in the Part or Mesh modules, it will look also rectangular. Even the undeformed model with scaling set to 1. I made an update, where I guess I found part of the issue.